# IE10 flexbox and word-wrap not working when I resize

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox, word-wrap

I am building a small css framework for mobile apps that i'll be releasing, but I don't understand why when I open the page in IE10 it seems all ok, but if I try to resize the page to a smaller size the text will lose it's wrap and display incorrectly.

Here it is an example of the problem:

http://matt93.altervista.org/mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `overflow: hidden` to the div directly under div.body.

I don't know **why** this fixed it in IE10, but I will say that IE10's support of flexbox is known to be a little shaky.

Also, I would recommend giving more class names to your divs. CSS like this:

```
.body > div {

}
```

will cause every div inside that wrapper to have those styles. It's better to apply class names and styles as-needed, especially if you want to release a framework for others to use.

Good luck!

Comment: I thank you so much! Maybe someone will reply to us and explain why! I use css with the direct child selector because I will also provide reactjs elements to be used together with the framework, but I will consider your suggestion! :D

Comment: I would also love to know the reason why, and you're welcome!